# how to load directly XML response instead of $xml->load('collection.xml')

Tags: php, xml

how to load replace $xml->load('collection.xml'); with myoutput

> // Load the XML source $xml = new DOMDocument;
>
> $xml->load('collection.xml'); // i have already xml output in $responce
>
> $xsl = new DOMDocument;
>
> $xsl->load('collection.xsl');
>
> // Configure the transformer $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
>
> $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); // attach the xsl rules
>
> echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);

Comment: It's not very clear, but are you looking for [`DOMDocument::loadXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

use

> $dom->loadXML($xml);

instead of

> $xml->load('collection.xml');